# How to pass value from a fragment/activity to xml?

Tags: java, android, xml

So I know data can be passed using `intent` between activities and fragments, but is there a way to pass the value to some **XML** files?

Say, I have the name and email from the login page, and I can pass it from from loginActivity to mainActivity (navigation) panel, but is there a way to pass it to `strings.xml` in `res\values` so I can refer to it at any time?

Comment: sounds like you need databinding https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding

Comment: No.  Strings.xml and res/values are hardcoded at compile time.  You can't alter them at runtime.  There may be a way to achieve what you're actually trying to do, but you need to describe that.

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: Save it to shared preference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not change /res/values in runtime because it is hardcoded.
We usually save key/value data in
[SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences)